# Get Maximum Log Size

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need get the Maximum Log Size from System Events (eventvwr.msc) in Windows >= 2003 through CMD.

I try with "reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security\ /v MaxSize" but I need only the value and decimal. With wevtutil only works in Windows 2008.

Please, I searched and find nothing, I know that is complicated, but I have them faith.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security" /v MaxSize') do set doc=%A
```

Is how to read stuff from registry.